# To convert date format to the time stamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

How to calculate the start of the day.

I calculate by
=> `moment().startOf('day').toISOString()`

it returns

> 2019-09-12T00:00:00.000

But I want to in this format **"2019-09-12 00:00:00.000"**

How can we get,Please help me.

Comment: Replace the `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var formatedDate= moment().startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,sss');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.toISOString()` method you can simply use `format()`.

As per momentjs doc [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)

> `.toISOString()` returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in
>   question is in local mode.

Use it like this:

```
moment().startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:SSS')
```

Hope this helps happy coding!!!

Comment: @Rahul Can you please accept this as an answer it resolved your issue? many thanks.